# TypeError: e[h] is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been using jquery 1.6 with no problem. Today I switched to jquery 1.8 and suddenly I am getting this error when trying to submit a form:

```
TypeError: e[h] is not a function.
```

Form:

```
<form method="post" action="login?login" name="login" id="login">
<input class="input" type="text" name="user_mail" id="user_mail" autocomplete="on" />
<input class="input" type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off" />
<a class="green_button" href="javascript:void(0)" id="login_button">Login</a>
<input type="submit" name="login" id="submit" style="visibility:hidden" />
</form>
<script language="javascript">
$("#login_button").click(function(){
    $("#login").submit();   
});
</script>
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Remove the line below.

```
<input type="submit" name="login" id="submit" style="visibility:hidden" />
```

***Update:***

Or if you have to use the submit input, then you need to change the id `submit` to something else. The reason is that if you have an input element with `id` of `submit`, it will set a `submit` property to the form with the HTMLInputElement. So you could not call the `.submit` method on the HTMLFormElement.

Comment: I added that since some browsers won't submit on enter. How can I achieve that without that line instead?

Comment: @Apog: You don't have to remove the element, just change the ID to something else than `submit`. The error message in Chrome was a bit more helpful: `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function`.

Comment: @FelixKling That woked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @FelixKling That's true, I think jQuery could prevent such problem by using `HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(the_form)`, but anyway, it is not good to have an id with `submit`.

Comment: @xdazz: Right, I was actually surprised that by that behaviour... but well, JavaScript and forms can be mysterious at times :)

Comment: just a note: same problem as OP described happens when using name="submit", not just id

Comment: This also breaks when the name is also called submit. E.g. `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">` will break.

Answer (score 6):

I waster 3 hours trying to fix the same issue, I was using the name='submit' for my submit button and was calling $("#form_name").submit(); in a function and was getting the error. Sometimes small things I overlook end up wasting lot of time.

Comment: what do you mean by wasted? is it a waste of time if apple invests 1000 hours into building a new phone glass or tesla invests 10.000 hours to create a new type of charger???

Comment: What I meant from wasted was that I didn't learn anything new from my mistake.

Comment: but you learned that it is waste of time to not learn anything. i know what you mean this is the bad side of being a programmer to do things a thousand times which you already know and dont learn anything...this is the reason why some projects run very slow: because they dont give you any new stuff to have fun with...then this leads doing errors in simple things...

Comment: oh ok ok ok ok :)

Answer (score 3):

i think it's because the line

```
<input type="submit" name="login" id="submit" style="visibility:hidden" />
```

can you remove it and retry?

Comment: it doesn't gives an error for me but nothing happens when i click on link. there are plenty of people complaining about jquery form problems and most of them have an element with id "submit"

Comment: You do not need to remove the line. Just change the value of the 'id' property to something else.

Answer (score 1):

When we use a submit type element in a form, This element will be set as Submit property of the form. So one could not call the submit() function with other element of form.

There are two ways to do this. first one is just remove the line as given in first reply.

Or **Use $("#submit").trigger("click"); instead of $("#login").submit();**. and it will **submit the form on pressing enter key word too.**

Answer (score 0):

Your `form` and `input` have the same name attribute value, `login`.

Change the `name` on the `input` to something else, like `submit`. This should clear up your error.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery 1.7 (possibly above too) if you have the `name` property also called `submit` it will break.

E.g.

`<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">`

Will not work, however:

`<input type="submit" name="sendSubmit" value="Upload">`

Is fine.