# form could not be submitted using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following script, it's just an example of my actual code, but it's behave the same as the actual one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="http://google.com/">
        <input type="text" name="item_name" />
        <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="save" />
        <a href="" id="save">Submit</a>
    </form>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            $('#save').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                $('form').submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see, there is `a` tag with id save, which is when this link is clicked, the form should submit, but it doesnt. this is caused by a hidden input with its name `submit`, if I change the name it just works well.

tried this on both chrome and firefox on linux. anyone can explain this?

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rL60x6a8/)

**-- EDIT --**

I tried using native click event:

```
document.getElementById('save').onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
}
```

form cannot be submited too.

Comment: @Pekka if i remove that line, the link will act as an usual link. form not submited

Comment: @.@ nah, it's a complex situtation actually...I use inline edit, that is why i use anchor tag

Comment: Somebody already asked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729319/how-send-a-form-with-javascript-when-input-name-is-submit - basically document.getElementById('redirectForm').submit is pointing to a DOM element and not to a function if there is an element with name = submit

Comment: woh cool thanks for pointing me out @kajyr

Comment: see the action attribute, removing e.preventDefault() doesnt make the form get submited, instead it's just go/refresh the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the same issue as this:
[TypeError: e[h] is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979852/typeerror-eh-is-not-a-function)

Having an input named submit adds a "submit" property to the form, meaning you can't call .submit() as a function.

You should name your hidden input something else.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML should look like this.

```
<form  action="index.php">
    <input type="text" name="item_name" />
    <a href="#" id="save">Submit</a>
</form>
```

You can fix it by using the trigger('submit')

```
jQuery(function($){
        $('#save').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('form').trigger('submit');

});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3xt381L/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the name of the input button from "submit" to something else. Having an element named "submit" causes the form's submit method to no longer work, which means the form cannot be submitted via JavaScript (at least, not easily).

The reason for this is because an input element named "submit" can be referenced by its name like this: form1.submit. That is, the input element is added as a property of the form object, with the property name being the name of the input element. That basically hides the submit function that is on the form's prototype.

Comment: indeed, I changed the field name to something else and then make adjustmen in the php file.